# reconstructing compressed dataframe information

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am collecting binary data using a pygame-based monitoring system which collects state data with a resolution close to but not exactly 0.2seconds. The object will be either on (1) or off (0) and will be monitored one hour, at the end of which  18,000 data-points will have been collected.

My problem is that Students will be reading this dataset using excel, so although it may be considered as a small dataset, viewed in excel it's simply overwhelming. I need this dataset to remain easily viewable and understandable (ie: when in csv form) so when I say I wish to compress dataframe size, I don't mean reduce its filesize using a general file-compression algorithm.

Most of the time the state of the object will be off. Meaning that perhaps 95% of my data-points will be unchanged from one time-point to the next. When there is a state-change to 'on', the 'on' state is usually going remain for much more than just 0.2 seconds.

Here is a short example of a typical dataframe, you can see that from the action column I am easily able to calculate the total time that something remains in an 'on' (or off) state, and matlotlib does a good job at visualising this data using a bar chart. But my issue is that a real the dataframe has a huge number of rows each for every 0.2 second timepoint (approximately).

I thought that I could reduce the dataframe size considerably by just recording the actions which differ from the last time-point. This does reduce the dataframe size, but it now complicates how the data is interpreted. For example, when plotting the new dataset, matplotlib doesn't know how long an 'on' state lasts and neither does my getOnStatePeriods function which is unable to properly measure the time-span for an on state. Please run the code below and look at the original data 'df', then look at my attempt to reduce the dataset size with 'dfSmall'.

This dataset isn't what I would consider to be a timeseries, since pygame is forcing the samples to be made at approximately 0.2 seconds and not EXACTLY at 0.2 seconds.

I'm comfortable with the techniques I'm using to measure on/off states using the full dataset, it just seems so inefficient to store all the timepoint events when nothing is changing. Maybe there is a better compression technique I should be using? Also, it seems that I am forced to use a bar plot rather than a simple 'plot' because a simple plot is giving me diagonal transitions...

Any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

try:
    # for Python2
    from cStringIO import StringIO 
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from io import StringIO

def getOnStatePeriods(df):
    mask = df['action']==0 #mask is True for specified event
    mask[0] = True # maybe worth setting 1st element in event to zero, or: mask[0] = True
    df.loc[mask,'step1'] = df.loc[mask,'time']
    df['step2'] = df['step1'].fillna(method='ffill')
    df['step3'] = df['time']-df['step2']
    df['step4'] = df['step3'].shift(1)
    df.loc[mask,'step5'] = df.loc[mask,'step4']
    df['step6'] = df['step5'].replace(0, np.nan)
    df['step7'] = df['step6'].shift(-1)
    df.rename(columns={'step7': 'actionTime'}, inplace=True)
    longDf = df # Make one detailed longDf and one concise df:
    df = df[['time','action','actionTime']]
    return df


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
time,action
.203,0
.401,0
.605,1
.802,1
1.001,0
1.201,0
1.403,1
1.606,1
1.803,1
2.004,0
2.201,0
2.407,0
'''.strip()))

dfSmall = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
time,action
.203,0
.605,1
1.001,0
1.403,1
2.004,0
'''.strip()))

df = getOnStatePeriods(df) #df based on the ORIGINAL large dataframe
dfSmall = getOnStatePeriods(dfSmall) # df containing only times of state changes

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,1, figsize=(6, 6), sharex=True)
axes[0].set_title("Original df")
axes[0].bar('time','action',data=df, color='red', align='edge', width=0.2)
axes[1].plot('time','action',data=df, color='red', alpha=0.5)
axes[2].set_title("'dfSmall' - where only state changes are recorded.")
axes[2].bar('time','action',data=dfSmall, color='blue', width=0.2)
axes[3].plot('time','action',data=dfSmall, color='blue', alpha=0.5)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: My attempt at compressing a dataframe]

Comment: you could use runlength encoding of your data - but what for? 18000 datapoints of 0 or 1 are peanuts. Do you have a spacelimitated integrated device or somthing wit hmission-critical memory constraints? you could also create a "bitset" of 0 and 1 and interprete your 18k values as one byteblob of ~2.25k byte's

Comment: I have amended my OP :
"My problem is that Students will be reading this dataset using excel, so although it may be considered as a small dataset, viewed in excel it's simply overwhelming. I need this dataset to remain easily viewable and understandable (ie: when in csv form) so when I say I wish to compress dataframe size, I don't mean reduce its filesize using a general file-compression algorithm."

I am not familiar with runlength encoding or byteblob, I'll check them out. I like the idea of deleting repeated values ... but maybe I'm making things difficult for myself?

Answer (score 1):

[Run-length encoding(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding):

```
import random
import sys

random.seed(42) 


def getValue(lastValue): 
    if random.randint(1,100)==100:  # 1% change chance
        return not lastValue
    return lastValue

data = []
lastValue = False
for _ in range(18000):
    lastValue=getValue(lastValue)
    data.append(lastValue)

print(data)

def runLengthEncoded(data):
    rl = []
    last = data[0]
    occ = 1
    for d in data[1:]:
        if d == last:
            occ += 1
        else:
            rl.append( (last,occ))
            occ = 1
            last = d
    rl.append( (last,occ) )
    return rl

rl = runLengthEncoded(data)

print(rl)
```

Output here:

```
[(False, 110), (True, 90), (False, 297), (True, 173), (False, 37), (True, 108), (False, 28), 
(True, 54), (False, 154), (True, 234), (False, 137), (True, 7), (False, 164), (True, 32), 
(False, 167), (True, 107), (False, 9), (True, 100), (False, 114), (True, 73), (False, 73), 
# snipp # 
(False, 156), (True, 23), (False, 373), (True, 86), (False, 122), (True, 82), (False, 250), 
(True, 75), (False, 207), (True, 102), (False, 42), (True, 14), (False, 359), (True, 324), 
(False, 48), (True, 123), (False, 135), (True, 120), (False, 136), (True, 145), (False, 82)]
```

The True/False are redundant, if you store the inital value you can shorten this even more. If you want to use timestamps, simply store the stamps where a value changes.

```
def runLengthEncoded2(data):
    rl = []
    last = data[0] 
    occ = 1
    for d in data[1:]:
        if d == last:
            occ += 1
        else:
            rl.append(occ)
            occ = 1
            last = d
    rl.append( occ )
    return (data[0],rl)
```

for:

```
(False, [110, 90, 297, 173, 37, 108, 28, 54, 154, 234, 137, 7, 164, 32, 167, 107, 9, 100, 114, 
         73, 73, 10, 21, 71, 35, 74, 238, 13, 20, 382, 112, 213, 67, 331, 13, 25, 74, 100, 48, 
         119, 74, 20, 72, 57, 86, 70, 283, 47, 26, 46, 12, 154, 14, 7, 129, 27, 69, 179, 129, 
         14, 33, 86, 9, 171, 36, 203, 81, 50, 28, 54, 58, 39, 108, 7, 34, 196, 139, 9, 205, 
         15, 45, 21, 209, 22, 40, 39, 19, 305, 15, 351, 24, 212, 3, 37, 26, 7, 150, 106, 176, 
         390, 61, 40, 194, 261, 89, 337, 457, 31, 53, 24, 487, 94, 334, 158, 446, 16, 300, 93, 
         5, 189, 62, 200, 136, 84, 75, 1, 179, 52, 19, 123, 54, 42, 130, 97, 77, 101, 11, 166, 
         85, 126, 156, 23, 373, 86, 122, 82, 250, 75, 207, 102, 42, 14, 359, 324, 48, 123, 135, 
         120, 136, 145, 82])
```